# A fixed navbar height across different screen widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've done a bootstrap project, and the navbar height was consistent across screen widths: which was fantastic.

This is a new project, and I can't figure out how to do it myself. I'm using only the grid system from bootstrap - nothing else.

**What is needed is a fixed navbar height when I change the width of the screen with chrome inspector tool**. Something I'm having a hard time achieving - even in a different cleaner file with just an index.html and style.css.

*I'm going mobile first in this project, so don't hurt your eyes* and I'm using a view port for 320px.*

[Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/m9b9zba3/)
https://jsfiddle.net/m9b9zba3/

HTML and CSS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Band Index Page</title>
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-grid-only.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <div class="band-hero col-xs-12">
            <div class="band-member-grid"><img src="../img/placeholder-sm.jpg" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="img-overlay content">
                <div class="member">
                  <div class="name"> </div>
                  <div class="role"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="member">
                  <div class="name"></div>
                  <div class="role"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="member">
                  <div class="name"></div>
                  <div class="role"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="member">
                  <div class="name"></div>
                  <div class="role"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="member">
                  <div class="name"></div>
                  <div class="role"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <section class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="upcmoing-gigs content">
            <div class="row">
              <article class="up-gig col-xs-4">
                <h4>date</h4>
                <h7>where</h7>
                <p>some details</p>
              </article>
              <article class="up-gig col-xs-4">
                <h4>date1</h4>
                <h7>where</h7>
                <p>some details</p>
              </article>
              <article class="up-gig col-xs-4">
                <h4>date2</h4>
                <h7>where</h7>
                <p>some details</p>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <article class="up-gig col-xs-4">
                <h4>date3</h4>
                <h7>where</h7>
                <p>some details</p>
              </article>
              <article class="up-gig col-xs-4">
                <h4>date4</h4>
                <h7>where</h7>
                <p>some details</p>
              </article>
              <article class="up-gig col-xs-4">
                <h4>date5</h4>
                <h7>where</h7>
                <p>some details</p>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section>
          <div class="logo"></div>
          <div class="blog-news col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="content">Latest news...</h2>
            <article></article>
          </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
          <nav class="navbar col-xs-12 row">
            <input type="checkbox"><span class="arrow-up col-xs-2"></span>
            <div class="content logo col-xs-2">Logo</div>
            <ul class="nav-right col-xs-12">
              <li class="nav-item content"><a>4</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item content"><a>Contact</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item content"><a>About</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item content"><a>Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
CSS:
    html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100
    }

    input {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0
    }

    .content {
        font-size: 3em
    }

    .row {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }

    img.img-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto
    }

    .up-gig {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 1%;
        border: 2px solid #000
    }

    .navbar {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #545454;
        list-style: none
    }

    .navbar .logo {
        width: 180px;
        height: 120px
    }

    .arrow-up {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 45px solid transparent;
        border-right: 45px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 45px solid #000;
        margin: 3% 4% 0;
        z-index: 1;
        float: right
    }

    .navbar li {
        height: 120px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative
    }

    .navbar li:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #828282
    }

    .navbar ul li a {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 34px
    }

    .navbar input[type=checkbox] {
        background-color: #800080;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 150px;
        height: 120px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 2%;
        z-index: 3
    }

    .nav-item {
        margin: auto 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 300
    }

    .navbar input {
        float: right
    }

    .nav-left {
        float: left
    }

    .nav-right {
        float: right
    }

    .navbar input[type=checkbox] ~ ul {
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: height .3s linear;
        transition: height .3s linear
    }

    .navbar input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul {
        height: 480px;
        -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
        transition: height .3s ease-in-out
    }

    .navbar input[type=checkbox] ~ span {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
        transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
        transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
        transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out
    }

    .navbar input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ span {
        margin-top: 4.3%;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s linear;
        transition: -webkit-transform .3s linear;
        transition: transform .3s linear;
        transition: transform .3s linear, -webkit-transform .3s linear
    }
```

P.S. I'm also using the checkbox hack to toggle the navbar on smaller screens.
I can't really get the site to scale like I wanted, but eh, I'll explore that later.
Thanks ahead of time :)

Comment: I'm confused. I see a fixed left side navbar; was expecting a top bar. You want a left navbar to be a fixed height?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please describe the current state and the desired state

Comment: Hi, the issue is when I use the chrome inspector tool, the navbar is responsive. I would like it to stay in a fixed height  when I change the width of the window using the chrome inspector. I'm still experimenting in a clean file, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the **height** of the **nav** to be consistent you need to give it a `height` value and make shure that the inner elements adapt to it.

```
.navbar {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #545454;
        list-style: none
        height: 150px; /* Put your desired height here*/
    }
```

If that isn't what you need, please explain a little more ;)

Comment: Hey MarioZ, thanks for the reply! In a clean file, it works when resize the window but not with the inspect tool. In thsi project is does not work with neither. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code in my Project:

If you want to give the height You can give it as static you want.

Also I have Used clearfix property to resolve the issue of Parent Container Height Collapse.

Hope it might help you.

```css
.main-header {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
 }

/* ---- Float clearfix ---- */

 .clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
 }
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="container clearfix">
   <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Best City Guide</a></h1>
   <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">ice cream</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">donuts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tea</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">coffee</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header><!--/.main-header-->
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! But when I inspect with chrome the size, including the height still changes. There is a way bootstrap 4 keep the height permanent despite changing the width of the window/inspector. - but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a little experimenting I found the solution:

I inserted in the head tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is what I've done in my previous project, it made the height stay fixed when changing the width of the window and chrome inspector!

Do you guys have any comments on this? **Good or bad practice? Is there a more elegant way to do so?**
Thanks again!